# What is the appropriate way to handle a rating api/function, in Ruby-on-Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, rating

Given the Ruby-on-Rails MVC framework, what is the best way to handle a rating api/function.

If I want to give users the ability to rate "stories", without actually editing them, what would be the best route to take. I don't want to put the story into edit mode, I just want to grab the story's ID and add a record in a Ratings table.

Would it be correct just to create a VIEW, in which the Ratings table is open for edit, but the linked stories are just in display mode???

Obviously I'm a beginner, when it comes to MVC and RonR, but I just want to get the proper way of doing this straight in my head :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have a ratings model which would store the association between all the ratings and all the stories.

From there you would have a ratings controller that would be there to mainly create a rating(as in a user rates a story).

When a user creates a rating, the request should go to the RatingsController#create.

On the story view page, you would link to the RatingsController#create by passing in the paramater of the story id through the GET paramaters(by using [nested resources](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources)).

Comment: Thank-you so much for the quick answer, makes complete sense. I think I'm finally wrapping my head around the MVC framework - the first couple of days it just wasn't "clicking" :)